# Assign selected TextAsset to new TextAsset variable (Unity, C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text

I'm working on a functionality to my text game that would make player choose from one scene (main menu) what level does he want to play via buttons and the information about his choice would be passed to next scene (game scene) where specific TextAsset would load.

Code:

```
        foreach (TextAsset d in DeckList)
        {
        if (d.name == CurrentDeckText)
            {
            questions = GetFile(d);
            }
        }
```

Currently, I have loaded all the texts of all levels at start of the game scene (inefficient, I know) as TextAssets and I have them put all in list (DeckList). When I click on button in Main Menu, code passes string name of level (CurrentDeckText). The name of the level is then compared with name of the TextAssets in list of loaded levels. In case of match, chosen level should be processed further down the line.

Problem is with the last step. Unity throws me this error
**NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Core.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Core.cs:172)**

I checked that:

1. d.name and CurrentDeckText are both strings and they match
2. All texts are loaded into DeckList
3. question = GetFile("name of level") works fine when I hardcode single level into it

I can't figure out what's the problem. I suspect there is something trivial I'm not seeing. Can you give me hand, Internet?

Comment: which line exactly is `172`? Could you show us a complete code please?

Comment: Sorry, It's with 'if' at the beginning.

Comment: So `d` is `null` for at least one entry of your list .. or the entire list ...  probably not referenced correctly via the Inspector? ... Or since you say you load them it sounds like the loading fails ...

Comment: It's not. I tried to load level by removing the matching loop and just manually wrote level name into GetFile() ... worked fine for all levels

Answer (score 0):

So I found a way around - instead of matching strings with name of the level I matched index from list with name of the level but instead of actual name I named the level buttons 0,1,2,3,.. and pass that to CurrentDeckText.

No idea why it works, but it does.